# update and 2 select statements in same query causing an error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a field c_id which has the entries with some values of CustomerIds.
I need to set those to null if those customer Ids are not valid as per the table.

I am using the following query. But it seems to throw an error:

```
update Customers set c_id=NULL where customer_id in (select customer_id from Customers where c_id not in (select customer_id from Customers);
```

Could someone help me identify the problem here

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error was with the closing bracket as mentioned by @Arulkumar . Is there a better way of doing this by using a JOIN or something?

Comment: Is my answer is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I avoided `IN` and used `JOINS` to fine tune your code:

```
UPDATE CUST SET C_Id = NULL 
FROM Customers CUST
LEFT JOIN Customers LJC ON LJC.Customer_Id = CUST.C_Id
WHERE LJC.Customer_Id IS NULL
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59fb1/5

I'm explain what I have done:

Created dummy table and data for `Customers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    Customer_Id  INT,
    C_Id    INT
)

INSERT INTO Customers
SELECT 1, 11 UNION
SELECT 2, 22 UNION
SELECT 22, 3 UNION 
SELECT 11, 4 UNION
SELECT 5, 6 UNION
SELECT 7, 8 UNION
SELECT 3, 9
```

Here 11, 22 and 3 are exists in `Customer_Id, C_Id`, So as per your request the other `C_Id` 4, 6, 8 and 9 those are not exist in `Customer_Id` are will `UPDATE` as `NULL`.

The below block will return the `C_Id` those are not exists in the `Customer_Id`

```
SELECT C1.C_Id
FROM Customers C1
LEFT JOIN Customers C2 ON C2.Customer_Id = C1.C_Id
WHERE C2.Customer_Id IS NULL
```

The below block will update `C_Id` as NULL from the above `SELECT` block

```
UPDATE Customers SET C_Id = NULL 
WHERE C_Id IN (
    SELECT C1.C_Id
    FROM Customers C1
    LEFT JOIN Customers C2 ON C2.Customer_Id = C1.C_Id
    WHERE C2.Customer_Id IS NULL
)
```

From the above block, if I remove the `IN` and modify using `JOIN`, the query what I gave in the top will come.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

Add `)` at the end of query for closing first select query

```
update Customers set c_id = NULL 
where customer_id in 
    (select customer_id 
     from Customers 
     where c_id not exists 
     (select customer_id from Customers)
    );
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? I know that this query looks weird. Iam relatively new to this.

Comment: Query looks okay... As for doing it better that depends on your table design